# How the last printf in this code work?

Tags: c, printf

This code makes an ASCII representation of a Sierpinski triangle of order 4, and I have no idea how the last `printf` works. If anyone can explain it to me, I would be very grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE (1 << 4)
int main()
{
    int x, y, i;
    for (y = SIZE - 1; y >= 0; y--, putchar('\n')) {
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) putchar(' ');
        for (x = 0; x + y < SIZE; x++)
            printf((x & y) ? "  " : "* ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? Do you know what the `&` operator does? Do you know the `? :` conditional operator? Break it down into pieces and it should become clear.

Comment: If `(x & y)` evaluates to true, it prints a "  ", otherwise a "* ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` is a ternary operator. It evaluates the expression on the left, and if it's non-zero (true) it selects the first value before the colon `:` and if it's zero (false) it selects the second.

Answer (score 1):

`printf((x & y) ? "  " : "* ");` is more or less equivalent to:

```
if ((x & y) != 0) {
    printf("  ");
}
else {
    printf("* ");
}
```

Comment: "more or less"? I'd say it's exactly equivalent. I resisted posting an almost identical answer.

Comment: I've gotten into the habit of saying "more or less" in answers like this because there's often some detail that's not important to the question/answer but is technically different.  It's a CYA that I just use without too much thought.